# how can contrib modules be enabled in install files without including the files?

Tags: distributions

I'm trying to make a quick simple install profile that I can use to get Drupal set up whenever I need a development environment.

There are contrib modules I want to enable as part of this, but I don't want to include them in the profile. I want to assume that they are already there in sites/all/modules (the reason for this is I will usually be creating a new install in a multisite).

I've set dependencies in the profile .info file, but the contrib modules do not get enabled by the install process.

Comment: Post here the file you are using; I use custom installation profile where the modules are in sites/all/modules and everything is installed properly.

Comment: Have you actually downloaded all the dependency modules and put them in sites/all/modules?